# Why do valgrind and gdb point to different lines of code? Or: How to malloc() and free() pointer of pointer in loop?

Tags: c++, gdb, valgrind

The loop in the following code can be executed a few times but then it crashes.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //not needed but program will not crash if I remove it
    int blocksize=stoi(argv[1]);
    //typical value 70-100
    int min_length=stoi(argv[2]);

    for(int i=0;i<250000;i++)
    {
        //Allocate memory for new integer array[row][col]. First allocate the memory for the top-level array (rows).
        int **output_std = (int**) malloc(20*sizeof(int*));

        //Allocate a contiguous chunk of memory for the array data values.
        output_std[0] = (int*) malloc( min_length*20*sizeof(int) );

        //Set the pointers in the top-level (row) array to the correct memory locations in the data value chunk.
        for (int k=1; k < 20; k++) 
        {
            output_std[k] = output_std[0]+k*min_length;
        }      

        //do something with output_std


        //free malloc'd space
        free(output_std[0]);
        for(int k=0;k<20;k++)
        {
            output_std[i]=NULL;
        }
        free(output_std);
        output_std=NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Debugging with `GDB` points to line 36: `free(output_std);`.
Debugging with `valgrind` yields the following error:

```
nvalid write of size 8
==32161==    at 0x4031A0: main (test.cpp:31)
==32161==  Address 0x82f2620 is 0 bytes after a block of size 160 alloc'd
==32161==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32161==    by 0x403159: main (test.cpp:16)
```

Line 16 is: `int **output_std = (int**) malloc(20*sizeof(int*));`

Line 31 is: `free(output_std[0]);`

Why do I get different positions for the error in my code?

How to proceed in such a situation?

(How can I fix my code?)

Edit: The lines are correct. I need such an object for a third party library.

Comment: Which line is 31? Deriving it from what you posted so far, it appears to be `free(output_std[0]);`.But it does not seem to be likely, judging by the partial message from valgrind. Are you sure this is this code you ran through valgrind? Are the line numbers accurate?

Comment: Why the heck are you using malloc and free and raw pointers in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind can often detect the problem earlier. That's the point of using it. Valgrind often catches the origin of the problem (or gets closer to the origin), while in GDB you can only see the consequences.

In your case the origin of the problem is heap memory corruption caused by an out-of-bounds write into an array. The consequence is crash inside `free` caused by that heap corruption. Valgrind catches the former. When you run your program (e.g. under GDB) you can only see the latter.

In your code

```
    for(int k=0;k<20;k++)
    {
        output_std[i]=NULL;
    }
```

the intended iteration variable is `k`. But you are accessing your array at `i`. At this point `i` is apparently `20`, which results in out-of-bounds access caught by valgrind.

I'd say this cycle is rather pointless anyway: you are trying to zero out memory that you are about to deallocate immediately after that. One can provide some arguments as to why it might make sense... But things like this are more appropriate inside the memory deallocation function itself, in debug version of the library. In user-level code it just clutters the code with unnecessary noise.

P.S. In any case, you apparently posted invalid line numbers. If `free(output_std)` is line 36, then the offending line should be seen by valgrind as 34, not 31. Please, next time post accurate code and strive to accurately identify the offending lines.

Answer (score 1):

`valgrind` replaces memory allocation and deallocation functions with its own instrumented versions. You can see that in the output:

```
at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

This is why under `valgrind` the application may crash in another place.